# Prove: $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\sec^{\;p} x) dx$ converges, $p > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\sec^{\;p} x) dx$ converges for all $p>0$.

I tried to do a change of variables through $u = \sec^{\;p} x$, but it is not sufficient to use the comparison test later.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If I take the absolute value of $cos(sec^{;p})$ and show that it absolutely converges on this interval, is it sufficient for my proof?

Answer (score 1):

Since $|cos(sec^{\;p} x)| \leq 1$, and $\int_0^{\pi/2} 1 dx$ converges, by the comparison test you can verify directly that your integral has absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $y=\sec^p (x)$ so that $x=\arctan\left(\sqrt{y^{2/p}-1}\right)$.  Then, $dx=\frac{1}{py\,\sqrt{y^{2/p}-1}}\,dy$.  Therefore, we have for $p>0$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos (\sec^p(x))\,dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos (y)}{py\sqrt{y^{2/p}-1}}\,dy$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: I thought about this change of variables, but since the cos(y) display both positive and negative values in this interval, I am not sure how to use a comparison test. Am I missing something?

Comment: The cosine function is bounded in absolute value by $1$.  The denominator is of order $y^{1+1/p}$, and $p>0$.  So, we have, in fact, absolute convergence.  Note that there is a new singularity at $y=1$.  But this is also a convergent improper integral.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark